# Definition of relative Whitehead product

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I can not find a definition of relative Whitehead product. Could someone explain this product to me?

Answer (score 3):

See if anyone of these papers helps

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.06118.pdf

https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/tmj1949/20/4/20_4_516/_pdf

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938371900309

Or, this book by Hans J. Baues
   Obstruction Theory: On Homotopy Classification of Maps